# Have remote shell evaluate expressions inside expect ssh script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

I have to use *expect* and *ssh* for automating on a remote shell (*bash* shell locally and remotely in my particular case). That is, I need to wrap `ssh someuser@example.com "echo This is \$(hostname)"` inside an `expect` script.

Running the above "manual" script, I get the expected output: `This is example.com`, so the `$(hostname)` expression (*command substitution*) gets evaluated on the remote machine.

Now I wrapped that ssh-remote-shell command inside an `expect` *here document*:

```
#/bin/bash

expect <<- DONE
  spawn ssh someuser@example.com "echo This is \\$(hostname)"
DONE
```

The wrapped script returns `[...] This is localhost` instead. So the `$(hostname)` expression gets evaluated on my local machine, not on the remote machine.

I've tried different levels of backslash escaping, single quotes and double quotes, `<<- DONE` and `<< DONE`, and moving `$(hostname)` to its own *expect* variable (i.e., `set someCommand "\\$hostname"`, then referencing `$someCommand`). But nothing helped.

How can I have the remote shell evaluate shell expressions in SSH *expect* scripts?

Comment: This is "just" a quoting problem. Use the heredoc form that does not interpolate the document: `expect <<- 'DONE'` (with the terminating word quoted) and the rest stays the same.

Comment: @glennjackman, in my case using `expect <<- 'DONE'` results in `can't read "(hostname)": no such variable while executing "spawn ssh someuser@example.com "echo This is \\$(hostname)""`

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

```
#!/bin/bash
expect <<- DONE
 set timeout 120
 spawn ssh dinesh@remote-lab "echo This is \\\$(hostname)"
 expect {
         "password: $" {send "welcome\r";exp_continue}
         eof
 }
DONE
```

**Output :**

```
dinesh@myPC:~/stackoverflow$ ./abdull
spawn ssh dinesh@remote-lab echo This is $(hostname)
dinesh@remote-lab's password: 
This is remote-lab
```

**Note :** The `spawn` statement can also be written as

```
 spawn ssh dinesh@remote-lab {echo This is \$(hostname)}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the dollar within braces, but you might want to use double quotes for echo's arguments: `spawn ssh who@where {echo "this is $(hostname)"}`

Comment: @Dinesh, thank you very much. Your solution brought me on the correct path. I was missing the `expect { ... }` part.